# Eazfuscator .NET or SmartAssembly which is better for security?

Tags: .net, security, crypto-obfuscator

I am deciding between Eazfuscator .NET and SmartAssembly. Both of these Obfuscators give me a credit for supporting a wide range of features to secure my .NET source.

I'm seeing more sympathy for SmartAssembly, as they've shown me quite a bit of proof that they're a relatively large company in terms of security, but their prices are relatively high for me at $675 for 1 year. . For Eazfuscator .NET it's only $399 (I don't know if it's the price for 1 year), but I didn't find too much information about their Eazfuscator .NET updates or being too clear about the information. believe the features of Eazfuscator .NET are available. Both are stating that they are supporting until 2023.

Answer (score 0):

before decide you need to test all with a free trial or demo version, for me i test a lot of obfuscators and i use now Babel and .NETReactor, give them a try.

https://blog.ndepend.com/in-the-jungle-of-net-obfuscator-tools/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).